# How to create a scrollable list of items to use with a TabLayout?

Tags: android, scroll, android-listfragment, android-tablayout

I'd like to first note that this is my first ever proper android app I'm making (I've only followed tutorials so far), so please be detailed in your answers and forgive me if I'm spouting nonsense :).

I'm trying to create an app where the main activity is going to be a TabLayout, and in one of the tabs I want to have a fragment that is a list which you can scroll up and down, and also I would like each element in the list to have multiple interactive elements (like two different buttons for example).

My first instinct was to go with a ListFragment because each element of the list will be a fragment that you can program to do whatever you want. However when following tutorials I found that ListFragments seem to be rather tricky, and I'm not sure if I can make it work with a TabLayout.

I've looked for other methods, but I've only found the kinds of solutions that allow you to have a list of just plain views, not fragments.

So what should I do? Is there a way you could make a ListFragment work with a TabLayout and I'm just being silly, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My first instinct was to go with a ListFragment because each element of the list will be a fragment that you can program to do whatever you want

The *contents* of a `ListFragment` will not be fragments. It is possible that the contents of a `ListFragment` will represent model objects for which you plan on showing other fragments elsewhere in your UI.

> I'm not sure if I can make it work with a TabLayout

A `ListFragment` can be used inside or outside of a `TabLayout`. I would not think that a `ListFragment` inside of a `TabLayout` would be particularly more troublesome than any other sort of fragment.

Your `ListFragment` problems will come from:

> I would like each element in the list to have multiple interactive elements (like two different buttons for example).

`ListView`, which underlies `ListFragment`, is tricky to use with interactive elements in list rows. As your design sounds rather unusual, you might wish to consider using other UI patterns rather than multiple buttons in list rows. If you insist upon this design, you may find `RecyclerView` to be a bit easier in the long run, even if it is more challenging at the outset.

> I've only found the kinds of solutions that allow you to have a list of just plain views, not fragments

That's the only thing you are ever going to find, in all likelihood. Again, `ListFragment` is a fragment that contains a `ListView`. `ListView` rows are not fragments, whether the `ListView` is contained in a `Fragment` or not. The only thing that I have ever heard of that is designed for vertical scrolling of fragments would be the various vertical `ViewPager` implementations floating around.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Indeed ListView is all about having a list of views (duh :D), but for some reason I remembered that each element is a fragment, my bad.

Since this is my first app and I have only very limited experience, I'll probably just adjust my UI so that each element in the list is just one big button by itself (kind of like the youtube app - you have a list of views that have a thumbnail, title etc. and you can tap the view anywhere and some action happens).

Comment: One more thing - I do know that what I was originally asking for can be made, since the 9gag app works in just this way - there is a TabLayout and each tab is some kind of scrolling thing where each element has a picture and multiple buttons that do different things. Though it's possible that they might have just implemented their own structure to achieve this.